# need to change default join column in One to Many and Many to One Mapping i n spring data jpa

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data jpa and want to change default join column happening between the entities. For example in the following mapping,

In Account.java,

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
   @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
   private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();
```

In Invoice.java

```
@ManyToOne
private Account account;
```

By default the `id` column of `Account` is getting joined with `account_id` of `Invoice` as per the given one to many and many to one mapping, which is also working fine for me. But now my requirement is instead of `account_id` in `Invoice` getting joined with `id` of `Account`, I want another field `account_number` of `Invoice` to be joined with `id` of `Account`, in my one to many and many to one mappings. Is it possible? As  a trail I made the following change to my `Invoice`

```
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="account_number", nullable=false)
 private Account account;
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.trace.domain.Invoice column: account_number (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Account.java

```
/**
 * Account
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Account implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "number", nullable = false)
    private String number;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "currency_code")
    private String currencyCode;

    @Column(name = "edi_type")
    private String ediType;

    @Column(name = "is_fedex_express_gsr")
    private Boolean isFedexExpressGsr;

    @Column(name = "is_fedex_ground_gsr")
    private Boolean isFedexGroundGsr;

    @Column(name = "is_ups_gsr")
    private Boolean isUpsGsr;

    @Column(name = "electronic_voiding")
    private Boolean electronicVoiding;

    @Column(name = "activate_signature_service")
    private Boolean activateSignatureService;

    @Column(name = "reject_invoices")
    private Boolean rejectInvoices;

    @Column(name = "notify_client_services")
    private Boolean notifyClientServices;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postalCode;


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<>();



    @ManyToOne
    private Courier courier;

    @ManyToOne
    private Client client;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "account_group_members",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "account_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<AccountGroup> accountGroups = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCurrencyCode() {
        return currencyCode;
    }

    public void setCurrencyCode(String currencyCode) {
        this.currencyCode = currencyCode;
    }

    public String getEdiType() {
        return ediType;
    }

    public void setEdiType(String ediType) {
        this.ediType = ediType;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFedexExpressGsr() {
        return isFedexExpressGsr;
    }

    public void setIsFedexExpressGsr(Boolean isFedexExpressGsr) {
        this.isFedexExpressGsr = isFedexExpressGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFedexGroundGsr() {
        return isFedexGroundGsr;
    }

    public void setIsFedexGroundGsr(Boolean isFedexGroundGsr) {
        this.isFedexGroundGsr = isFedexGroundGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getIsUpsGsr() {
        return isUpsGsr;
    }

    public void setIsUpsGsr(Boolean isUpsGsr) {
        this.isUpsGsr = isUpsGsr;
    }

    public Boolean getElectronicVoiding() {
        return electronicVoiding;
    }

    public void setElectronicVoiding(Boolean electronicVoiding) {
        this.electronicVoiding = electronicVoiding;
    }

    public Boolean getActivateSignatureService() {
        return activateSignatureService;
    }

    public void setActivateSignatureService(Boolean activateSignatureService) {
        this.activateSignatureService = activateSignatureService;
    }

    public Boolean getRejectInvoices() {
        return rejectInvoices;
    }

    public void setRejectInvoices(Boolean rejectInvoices) {
        this.rejectInvoices = rejectInvoices;
    }

    public Boolean getNotifyClientServices() {
        return notifyClientServices;
    }

    public void setNotifyClientServices(Boolean notifyClientServices) {
        this.notifyClientServices = notifyClientServices;
    }

    public Boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setIsActive(Boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public Courier getCourier() {
        return courier;
    }

    public void setCourier(Courier courier) {
        this.courier = courier;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public Set<Invoice> getInvoices() {
        return invoices;
    }

    public void setInvoices(Set<Invoice> invoices) {
        this.invoices = invoices;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Account shipper = (Account) o;

        if (!Objects.equals(id, shipper.id))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" + "id=" + id + ", number='" + number + "'" + ", name='" + name + "'" + ", currencyCode='"
                + currencyCode + "'" + ", ediType='" + ediType + "'" + ", isFedexExpressGsr='" + isFedexExpressGsr + "'"
                + ", isFedexGroundGsr='" + isFedexGroundGsr + "'" + ", isUpsGsr='" + isUpsGsr + "'"
                + ", electronicVoiding='" + electronicVoiding + "'" + ", activateSignatureService='"
                + activateSignatureService + "'" + ", rejectInvoices='" + rejectInvoices + "'"
                + ", notifyClientServices='" + notifyClientServices + "'" + ", isActive='" + isActive + "'"
                + ", address='" + address + "'" + ", city='" + city + "'" + ", state='" + state + "'" + ", postalCode='"
                + postalCode + "'" + '}';
    }
}
```

Invoice.java

```
/**
 * A Invoice.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "invoice")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Invoice implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name = "invoice_number")
    private String invoiceNumber;

    @Column(name = "invoice_amount")
    private Double invoiceAmount;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "edi_number")
    private String ediNumber;

    @Column(name = "bill_date")
    private Date billDate;

    @Column(name = "courier_id")
    private Long courierId;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_number", nullable=true)
    private Account account;



    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
    //@JsonIgnore
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    private Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetailss = new HashSet<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getInvoiceNumber() {
        return invoiceNumber;
    }

    public void setInvoiceNumber(String invoiceNumber) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }

    public Double getInvoiceAmount() {
        return invoiceAmount;
    }

    public void setInvoiceAmount(Double invoiceAmount) {
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getEdiNumber() {
        return ediNumber;
    }

    public void setEdiNumber(String ediNumber) {
        this.ediNumber = ediNumber;
    }


        public Date getBillDate() {
            return billDate;
        }

        public void setBillDate(Date billDate) {
            this.billDate = billDate;
        }

        public Long getCourierId() {
            return courierId;
        }

        public void setCourierId(Long courierId) {
            this.courierId = courierId;
        }

        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

        public void setAccount(Account account) {
            this.account = account;
        }

    public Set<InvoiceDetails> getInvoiceDetailss() {
        return invoiceDetailss;
    }

    public void setInvoiceDetailss(Set<InvoiceDetails> invoiceDetailss) {
        this.invoiceDetailss = invoiceDetailss;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Invoice invoice = (Invoice) o;

        if ( ! Objects.equals(id, invoice.id)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Invoice{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", accountNumber='" + accountNumber + "'" +
                ", invoiceNumber='" + invoiceNumber + "'" +
                ", invoiceAmount='" + invoiceAmount + "'" +
                ", ediNumber='" + ediNumber + "'" +
                ", status='" + status + "'" +
                ", billDate='" + billDate + "'" +
                ", courierId='" + courierId + "'" +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: If Account is mapped to the account_number column, you shouldn't have another column mapped to that same column, yet you seem to have one. Post your complete entity. Why use account_number instead of account_id, since the column does indeed contain the account ID, and not the account number?

Comment: The reason is due to some  miss communication, one of our developer has populated data in to these tables for account number, instead account_id using back end procedures and queries, now to reload all that data to account_id would be little time taking for us. We can update account_id with account_number data but I am thinking a solution in the line I have mentioned in my posted question. I am editing my question with complete entities.

Comment: So you'll leave that confusing mess there forever instead of renaming two columns of the table?

Comment: No, I will change this soon as it requires modification in many other procedures and queries, etc. Meanwhile I thought of solving that in this manner and it also helps as a part of learning curve to improve my spring data jpa concepts.

Comment: OK. So just remove the field `private String accountNumber;` (and its annotation of course). It's redundant and useless, since account_number is the column used to map the account field.

Comment: yes it is working fine now with account number, as join column, thanks. You can post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, there are two different mappings for the same column: account_number. And indeed, you have

```
@Column(name = "account_number")
private String accountNumber;
```

in your entity, which is redundant with the account field.

You just need to remove that field.

Comment: JB Nizet, In the above scenrio, the query is forming as select invoice0_.id as id1_9_, invoice0_.account_number as account_8_9_,
 invoice0_.invoice_number as invoice_6_9_, invoice0_.status as status7_9_ 
 from invoice invoice0_ cross join account account1_
 where invoice0_.account_number=account1_.id and invoice0_.courier_id=? and account1_.client_id=?

Comment: JB Nizet, In the above scenrio, the query is forming as select invoice0_.id as id1_9_, invoice0_.account_number as account_8_9_,
invoice0_.status as status7_9_   from invoice invoice0_ cross join account account1_ where invoice0_.account_number=account1_.id and invoice0_.courier_id=? and account1_.client_id=?. What I need to do if  I want to change the change the condition to  invoice0_.account_number=account1_.number instead  invoice0_.account_number=account1_.id. Here  account1_.number is another filed that I have added to account table.

Comment: You add a `referenedColumnName = "number"` in the JoinColumn annotation: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29. But you'd better fix your database schema. Forign keys should reference primary keys.

Comment: Sure I am simultaneously working on that one. When I  make the this change, @OneToMany(mappedBy="account"), @JoinColumn(name="number"), I am getting the following error. Caused by : org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association marked as mappedBy must not define database mappings like JoinTable or @JoinColumn : com.sample.domain.Account.Invoices

Comment: Why do you do something completely different from what I told you to do? You must NOT have a JoinColumn annotation on the OneToMany. You must have a `referencedColumnName = "number"` attribute on the existing JoinColumn annotation, located on the `account` field of the `Invoice` entity.

Comment: solved by using referencedColumnName as suggested, thanks